# How to add AD authentication in my Chat bot - MS bot framework v4

Tags: c#, authentication, botframework, azure-qna-maker

I'm developing a chat bot using MS bot framework v4 SDK in C#.

I've chosen [Dispatch bot sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/14.nlp-with-dispatch) as my base, Since I'm using QnA maker and Luis. Now i want to add an authentication to access my bot. As per the sample [Authentication Bot](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/18.bot-authentication) I've added all the dependency including the nuget packages, methods and classes in my bot project code, but still the authentication is not working for me, it throws an exception error and gives sorry something went wrong error. There could be some issue with the way of integration and calling the correct methods.

if any one has solution or sample of a bot with both authentication and QnA Maker used, please do share me.

**My code:**
**Dispatchbot.cs**

```
    namespace Microsoft.BotBuilderSamples
{

    public class DispatchBot<T> : ActivityHandler where T : Dialog
    {

        private ILogger _logger;
        private IBotServices _botServices;
        private BotState _conversationState;
        private BotState _userState;
        protected readonly Dialog Dialog;


        public DispatchBot(ConversationState conversationState, UserState userState, T dialog, ILogger<DispatchBot<T>> logger, IBotServices botServices)

        {
            _conversationState = conversationState;
            _userState = userState;
             Dialog = dialog;
            _logger = logger;
            _botServices = botServices;


        }

        [HttpGet]
        protected override async Task OnMessageActivityAsync(ITurnContext<IMessageActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            await Dialog.RunAsync(turnContext, _conversationState.CreateProperty<DialogState>(nameof(DialogState)), cancellationToken);
            /*....my custom logic..........*/

        }

        //added for authentication
        protected override async Task OnTokenResponseEventAsync(ITurnContext<IEventActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Running dialog with Token Response Event Activity.");

            // Run the Dialog with the new Token Response Event Activity.
            await Dialog.RunAsync(turnContext, _conversationState.CreateProperty<DialogState>(nameof(DialogState)), cancellationToken);
        }

        //added code for welcome message on page load
        protected override async Task OnEventActivityAsync(ITurnContext<IEventActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {

          var oneventconversationStateAccessors = _conversationState.CreateProperty<oneventvalues>(nameof(oneventvalues));
          var onevntconversationData = await oneventconversationStateAccessors.GetAsync(turnContext, () => new oneventvalues());

            var objectdata = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(turnContext.Activity.Value.ToString());

               data _data = new data();
               _data.prodselected = objectdata["Product"];
               _data.relselected = objectdata["Release"];
               _data.hour = objectdata["Hour"];

                /*....my custom logic..........*/


        }
        public class data
        {
            public string prodselected { get; set; }
            public string relselected { get; set; }
            public int hour { get; set; }


        }
        protected override async Task OnMembersAddedAsync(IList<ChannelAccount> membersAdded, ITurnContext<IConversationUpdateActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var userStateAccessors = _userState.CreateProperty<UserProfile>(nameof(UserProfile));
            var userProfile = await userStateAccessors.GetAsync(turnContext, () => new UserProfile());

            foreach (var member in membersAdded)
            {
               if (member.Id != turnContext.Activity.Recipient.Id)
             {
                    userProfile.Name = member.Name.Replace('.', ' ');
                    await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text($"Hi  **{member.Name.Replace('.',' ')}**. I'm your Assistant."), cancellationToken);
                    User = member.Name;
                }
            }

        }
        //added from statemanagement
        public override async Task OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
        {
            if (turnContext?.Activity?.Type == ActivityTypes.Invoke && turnContext.Activity.ChannelId == "msteams")
                await Dialog.Run(turnContext, _conversationState.CreateProperty<DialogState>(nameof(DialogState)), cancellationToken);
            else
                await base.OnTurnAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken);

            // Save any state changes that might have occured during the turn.
            await _conversationState.SaveChangesAsync(turnContext, false, cancellationToken);
            await _userState.SaveChangesAsync(turnContext, false, cancellationToken);

        }

        private async Task DispatchToTopIntentAsync(ITurnContext<IMessageActivity> turnContext, string intent, RecognizerResult recognizerResult, CancellationToken cancellationToken, ConversationData conversationData)
        {
            switch (intent)
            {
                case "q-qna-1":
                    await Process1(turnContext, cancellationToken,conversationData);
                    break;
                case "q-qna-2":

                    await Process2(turnContext, cancellationToken, conversationData);
                    break;
                default:
                    _logger.LogInformation($"Dispatch unrecognized intent: {intent}.");

            }
        }
               /*....my custom logic methods.........*/

        }
```

**Authbot.cs**

```
namespace Microsoft.BotBuilderSamples
{
    public class AuthBot<T> : DispatchBot<T> where T : Dialog
    {

        public AuthBot(ConversationState conversationState, UserState userState, ILogger<DispatchBot<T>> logger, T dialog, IBotServices botServices )
              : base(conversationState, userState, dialog, logger, botServices)
        {
        }

        protected override async Task OnMembersAddedAsync(IList<ChannelAccount> membersAdded, ITurnContext<IConversationUpdateActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            foreach (var member in turnContext.Activity.MembersAdded)
            {
                if (member.Id != turnContext.Activity.Recipient.Id)
                {
                    await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text("Welcome to AuthenticationBot ."), cancellationToken);
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

**MainDialog:**

```
    namespace Microsoft.BotBuilderSamples
{
    public class MainDialog : LogoutDialog
    {
        protected readonly ILogger Logger;

        public MainDialog(IConfiguration configuration, ILogger<MainDialog> logger)
            : base(nameof(MainDialog), configuration["ConnectionName"])
        {
            Logger = logger;

            AddDialog(new OAuthPrompt(
                nameof(OAuthPrompt),
                new OAuthPromptSettings
                {
                    ConnectionName = ConnectionName,
                    Text = "Please Sign In",
                    Title = "Sign In",
                    Timeout = 300000, // User has 5 minutes to login (1000 * 60 * 5)
                }));

            AddDialog(new ConfirmPrompt(nameof(ConfirmPrompt)));

            AddDialog(new WaterfallDialog(nameof(WaterfallDialog), new WaterfallStep[]
            {
                PromptStepAsync,
                LoginStepAsync,
                DisplayTokenPhase1Async,
                DisplayTokenPhase2Async,
            }));

            // The initial child Dialog to run.
            InitialDialogId = nameof(WaterfallDialog);
        }

        private async Task<DialogTurnResult> PromptStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(OAuthPrompt), null, cancellationToken);
        }

        private async Task<DialogTurnResult> LoginStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            // Get the token from the previous step. Note that we could also have gotten the
            // token directly from the prompt itself. There is an example of this in the next method.
            var tokenResponse = (TokenResponse)stepContext.Result;
            if (tokenResponse != null)
            {
                await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text("You are now logged in."), cancellationToken);
                return await stepContext.PromptAsync(nameof(ConfirmPrompt), new PromptOptions { Prompt = MessageFactory.Text("Would you like to view your token?") }, cancellationToken);
            }

            await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text("Login was not successful please try again."), cancellationToken);
            return await stepContext.EndDialogAsync(cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
        }

        private async Task<DialogTurnResult> DisplayTokenPhase1Async(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text("Thank you."), cancellationToken);

            var result = (bool)stepContext.Result;
            if (result)
            {
                // Call the prompt again because we need the token. The reasons for this are:
                // 1. If the user is already logged in we do not need to store the token locally in the bot and worry
                // about refreshing it. We can always just call the prompt again to get the token.
                // 2. We never know how long it will take a user to respond. By the time the
                // user responds the token may have expired. The user would then be prompted to login again.
                //
                // There is no reason to store the token locally in the bot because we can always just call
                // the OAuth prompt to get the token or get a new token if needed.
                return await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(OAuthPrompt), cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
            }

            return await stepContext.EndDialogAsync(cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
        }

        private async Task<DialogTurnResult> DisplayTokenPhase2Async(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var tokenResponse = (TokenResponse)stepContext.Result;
            if (tokenResponse != null)
            {
                await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text($"Here is your token {tokenResponse.Token}"), cancellationToken);
            }

            return await stepContext.EndDialogAsync(cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
        }
    }
}
```

Final Error message in exception:

> unable to get the bot AppId from the audience claim.

Comment: Can you share the code in your bot? Also, the "Something went wrong" message is just what is shown in the conversation. You should have a full error message logged to console (or wherever you are logging errors). If you could provide that too that would be very helpful.

Comment: @billoverton thanks for replying, I've added the required details, pls let know what I'm missing for authentication, as far as my debugging, My bot project is not hitting on the botstate.cs file, whereas the authentication sample bot does that and gives sign in option

Answer (score 0):

For requests from channel, App Id is in Audience claim of JWT token. The error 'unable to get the bot App ID from the audience claim' is because it is not able to fetch the appID out of the turn state and it is null. Rather than directly adding the authentication bot sample, I would recommend following the [Add Authentication to a bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=aadv1%2Ccsharp) documentation which provides step-wise  instructions on adding code to your bot. It will make it easy for you to narrow down on if you missed any step. I would also suggest to double-check if the Azure AD app was configured correctly and you are able to get the token generated.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for replying, actually i followed the document did all the steps in azure portal and got everything done till the connection name, and in the document they again mentioned the same authentication bot as a sample code, and thus i've ended up with the issue.